# Accessing localhost outside of server

Tags: linux, networking, apache-http-server

I am new to node.js and am trying to get into the hang of actually using it. I am very familiar with JavaScript so the language itself is self-explanatory but the use of Node.js is quite different from the browser implementation.

I have my own remote virtual server and have installed Node and the Package Manager and everything works as expected. I am not exactly a server extraordinaire and have limited experience with the Terminal and Apache Configurations.

I can run my server using:

```
nodejs index.js
```

Which gives me: `listening on *:3300` as expected.

I can then access my localhost from the terminal using: `curl http://localhost:3300/` which gives me the response I expect.

Given that the website that links to my server is `https://example.com`, I am trying to connect to this server using `http://example.com:3300/` without success as I just get `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. I am not sure how to gain access to it.

Comment: What exactly does “Given that the website that links to my server” mean? Do you have a domain with its A and/or AAAA records pointing at your server’s IP address? Do you have any firewalls in place? Is your VPS perhaps hosted at Microsoft Azure or Amazon AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing localhost is not the problem since you're already listening on * (which means all interfaces). In order for anyone to access your sever using the name "example.com", it has to resolve to an ip that will reach your server from the client machine. What that means depends on your environment.

For testing, if you are attempting to access the site from the same machine that is running node.js (which is only suitable for testing), I suggest adding the loopback address to the system dns name cache. /etc/hosts on unix and Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts on most windows. As stated, this is only good for testing: add the line: `127.0.0.1 example.com` to the end of the file on its own line.

For production use, so other people can access your site, you need a dns (domain name service) provider to bind your name to your public ip. This will cost around $10/year. You also need a public IP that is not blocked by other people's isps, and preferably one that does not change very often. This can range from facilitated-redirection (not recommended, if only for bandwidth and availability limitations) to small hosting applications ($25-$100/year and up, depending on space and computing needs).

Both these services are offered by cloud providers, just search for cloud hosting services. Popular providers include go daddy and amazon web services. I have had better experiences with AWS.

Also, exposing nodejs to a public ip is probably not the best idea. I further suggest you look into some middleware like apache or nginx to wrap your application in something that listens to tradition http requests.

**Edit in response to comment:**

In that case you want to define a partial url path in your apache configs. This is known as a reverse proxy, meaning that you define a rule for what urls/requests should be redirected (proxied) to node.js and apache will direct them there for you. See apache docs here and this serverfault question:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

https://serverfault.com/questions/497856/using-an-apache-virtualhost-to-access-a-node-js-instance-on-the-same-server

Note that the apache docs tend to assume the backend application is running on another server, but it works the same for localhost. You want proxypass and proxypassreverse directives.

Comment: I guess I was not very clear. I already have a server up and running with apache (hence the apache tag). Meaning example.com is already hooked up with a DNS and is live on the web. Accessing example.com:443 works correctly as this is the SSL port I have designated for it. I am trying to also get port 3300 to work for my node application

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `const hostname = '127.0.0.1';`

Do: `const hostname = '0.0.0.0';`